# how to concatenate two numpy.ndarrays?

Tags: python, numpy

How can I extend two ndarrays ?

for instance,

```
df = np.fromfile(f"/data/8d6ea70b_bitmex_XBTUSD_0001.dat", dtype)

df.extend( np.fromfile(f"/data/8d6ea70b_bitmex_XBTUSD_0002.dat", dtype) )
```

Comment: I neither see two numpy arrays in  your post, nor the expected output or your attempt.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

Comment: Numpy arrays don't have an `extend` method.  They aren't lists.  There is a poorly named `np.append`, but I prefer that people use `np.concatenate`.  But take time to read its docs.

Answer (score 4):

To concatenate two numpy arrays, use concatenate:

```
v1 = np.fromfile(f"/data/8d6ea70b_bitmex_XBTUSD_0001.dat", dtype)
v2 = np.fromfile(f"/data/8d6ea70b_bitmex_XBTUSD_0002.dat", dtype)
v = np.concatenate((v1, v2))
```

Then use them for a dataframe (your question being concatenating numpy arrays, not dataframes).